# I can't add class attribute in my html code. When I type class it appears like a normal text not an attribute. I created a list then I add class and

Tags: html, class, visual-studio-code, attributes

can't add class attribute in my html code. When I type class it appears like a normal text not an attribute. I created a list then I add class and it only appears as normal text.

Comment: You should give more info about what you are trying to do, what you have done, maybe some code snippet, or a detailed explanation. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.